# Horizontally centered div with a div next to it, kind of responsive-ly

Tags: xml, html, css

Here's my code:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div>
        Example Content    
    </div>
    <span>
        Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
    </span>
</div>
```

```
#container
{
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 3em 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container > div
{
    display: inline-block;
    background: #777;
    padding: 3em;
}
```

and a fiddle of my current situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/zu0f6jcm/

Now my questions are;
**a)** How can I center the inner `div`, so that the `span` doesn't affect it's position?
and
**b)** How can I keep the `span` inline with the inner `div`, unless there's not enough space to display the `span` on one line, in which case it should move below the inner `div`?

To clarify **b)**: the behaviour I'm looking for is kind of like when you add

```
span
{
    float: right;
}
```

to the current fiddle, while taking into account the **a)**. I should also preferably be able to position the span with margins and what not.

Without JS.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning you're looking for can be achieved by modifying your CSS like this:

```
#container {
    background: #aaa;
    padding: 3em 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative:  /* additional style */
}

/* no changes to the '#container > div' rule */

#container span {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 3em 0;  /* copied this from your padding above, mod as necessary */
    right: 0;        /* adjust this to whatever positioning you need */
    top: 0;          /* adjust this to whatever positioning you need */
}
```

This will not automatically handle the "move to the bottom if there's not space" part of your question, however.  For that, you'll need to use media queries and change your style rules at different device widths.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of how you could achieve it with floats:

```
 <div id='container'>
     <div>
         &nbsp;
     </div>
     <div id="content">
         Example Content    <br/>
         Example Content
     </div>
     <div>
     Bla Bla Bla Bla Bla
     </div>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 #container{
     background: #aaa;
     padding: 3em 0;
     text-align: center;
     position:relative;
     overflow: auto;
 }
 #container > div {
    float:left;
    width:33%;
 }

 #container #content{
     background: #777;
     min-width:200px;
 }
```

Your last div will wrap when there is not enough room for it to take up 33% of the screen with the #content containers min-width set to what-ever value you want for this.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s4secygm/